# Namespace Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Please Help me to resolve this error in unity

Assets\ParticleScaler\ParticleScaler.cs(93,3): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ParticleEmitter' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Put your cursor on `ParticleEmitter` and hit CTRL+PERIOD.

Comment: which unity version are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ParticleEmitter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/540/Documentation/ScriptReference/ParticleEmitter.html) was part of the [**Legacy** particle system used prior to Unity Version **3.5**](https://docs.unity3d.com/540/Documentation/Manual/comp-ParticlesLegacy.html) and already marked as **obsolete** back in `Unity 5.4` and afaik got **deprecated** in `2018.3`. Until `2018.2` is was still part of the [`UnityEngine.ParticlesLegacyModule`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/UnityEngine.ParticlesLegacyModule.html)

---

After `Unity 3.5` there is now the "new" [`ParticleSystem`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.html) and maybe the [`ParticleSystem.emission`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem-emission.html)(→[`ParticleSystem.EmissionModule`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.EmissionModule.html)) is what you are looking for

Comment: @K.Oussama If derHugo's answer is the accepted answer for your question, please mark it as accepted.